# What is the relationship between PMU and PEBS for intel CPU?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I know for intel CPU families, there are `PMU` (Performance Monitoring Unit) and `PEBS` (Precise Event Based Sampling). What is the relationship between them? Per my understanding, the `PMU` contains `PEBS`, is it right?